# Trouble with WCF (net.tcp) endpoint discovery using svcutil

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

I have a project where I'm trying to implement a simple WCF service over TCP transport.This is what the service side code is shared below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HwWcfService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string Uri = string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:8000/TelemetryProviderService");
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
                    typeof(Calculator),
                    new Uri(Uri)
                    );


            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);                
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(ICalc),
                binding,
                "CalcService");

            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Done starting the new endpoint...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }



    class Calculator :ICalc
    {

        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y);
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}





namespace HwWcfService
{
    [ServiceContract(
        Namespace="HwWcfService"
    )]
    interface ICalc
    {

        [OperationContract]
        int Add(int x, int y);
    }
}
```

The App.Config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="HwWcfService.Calculator">
          <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/TelemetryProviderService" 
                    name="TelemetryProviderService"
                    contract="HwWcfService.ICalc"
                    binding="netTcpBinding"  
                    bindingConfiguration="calcTcpBindingConfiguration"
                    behaviorConfiguration="epBehaviourConfig"
                    />

          <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/TelemetryProviderServiceMex"
                    name ="TelemetryProviderServiceMex"
                    binding="mexTcpBinding"
                    contract="HwWcfService.ICalc"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit"
                    />
        </service>
      </services>

      <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="calcTcpBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:02:00"/>
        </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>


      <behaviors>

        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="epBehaviourConfig">
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>

        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetUrl="false" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>

      </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I run svcutil.exe to query all the params I get the error:
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost:8000/TelemetryProviderService

If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the spe
ified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.

WS-Metadata Exchange Error
    URI: net.tcp://localhost:8000/TelemetryProviderService

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8000/TelemetryProviderService'.

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote hos
```

, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:04:59.9929977'.

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetUrl="false" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
```

You need to set both of these to true in order for svcutil.exe to be able to query your service.

From MSDN on svcutil.exe:

> When you use Svcutil to access a WSDL document that has a reference to
>   a security token service (STS), Svcutil makes a WS-MetadataExchange
>   call to the STS. However, the service can expose its WSDL documents
>   using either WS-MetadataExchange or HTTP GET. Therefore, if the STS
>   has only exposed the WSDL document using HTTP GET, a client written in
>   WinFX will fail. For clients written in .NET Framework 3.5, Svcutil
>   will attempt to use both WS-MetadataExchange and HTTP GET to obtain
>   the STS WSDL.

**Edit:** Also on checking the MSDN for `<serviceMetadata/>` you need to change it to the following:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
```

By default you should not be able to access the WSDL for the web service via your endpoint address but including "?wsdl" in the URL.

Link: [MSDN <serviceMetadata> Element Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)